# How to build a un-minified version of Shopware 6 administration scripts for debugging purpose?

Tags: debugging, webpack, shopware, shopware6

I would like to debug the following not-very-helpful error message when trying to save a custom CMS component in Shopware 6 administration layout editor:

```
An error was captured in current module: undefined
errorCaptured @ app.js?16504701226454027:1
Xe @ vendors-node.js?16504701221582962:2
(anonymous) @ vendors-node.js?16504701221582962:2
Promise.catch (async)
Ge @ vendors-node.js?16504701221582962:2
n @ vendors-node.js?16504701221582962:2
o._wrapper @ vendors-node.js?16504701221582962:2
```

When having such problems in the store front, I usually modify build-storefront.sh to call

`npm --prefix "${STOREFRONT_ROOT}"/Resources/app/storefront run development`

instead of

`npm --prefix "${STOREFRONT_ROOT}"/Resources/app/storefront run production`

Now I want to adapt `build-administration.sh` in a similar way:

The original line is

`(cd "${ADMIN_ROOT}"/Resources/app/administration && npm clean-install && npm run build)`

When I change it to

`(cd "${ADMIN_ROOT}"/Resources/app/administration && npm install && mode=development npm run dev)`

I would call

`"dev": "mode=development webpack-dev-server",`

`vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/package.json`

I do not want to use the dev server and changed this to

`"dev": "mode=development webpack",`

No the build runs, but I still get a minified `app.js` as a result.

How can I debug the initial problem further?

Comment: When doing a dev build or watching, it should be generating .map files. The app.js will still be minified but the map files will allow you to view and debug the javascript.

Comment: Hm, okay, have to check that. But how is the recommended way to do a dev build (without watching)?.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken you can't. The only way to debug is to use `administration:watch` or `storefront:hot-proxy` which will build as normal but include the source maps for debugging